# Printing List[List[List[String]]] in scala

Tags: string, list, scala

I wish to print element of List[List[List[String]]]  nicely.
I have tried using foreach function but it failed.
Is there a built-in function for it?

Comment: "I have tried using foreach function but it failed." In what way did it fail? "nicely" - define, please. Do you want the structure of the list preserved in the result? Have you tried `.mkString?`

Comment: Well, `println(List(List(List("string"))))` doesn't show anything...

Comment: mkString doesn't work good since it prints some of the list with the structure "List(....)" - i solved it by creating a method that prints it but it is not so elegant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just print all elements use `flatten` method:

```
list.flatten.foreach(println)
```